# Fan-out and subsequent synchronization with celery

Tags: python, celery

I am working on a (at least I think so) simple fan-out system using python (2.x) and celery. The basic idea is to run some variations of an algorithm on each of a group of input documents and then do the same for the outputs with another algorithm (and so on, for a few times). So more or less:

```
       doc1
        /|\
doc1_1 doc1_2 doc1_3
  /|\  /|\      /|\
doc1_1_2 ....
```

Additionally it would be helpful to be able to synchronize at a certain point in this execution chain. This is not crucial but would decrease overall execution time.

I tried creating and executing groups in a task but there is no way to find out if these subtasks failed or even finished. Building a large number of chains seems somewhat unelegant (C programmer here so no claim to authority) but at least I'd be able to retrieve the current status of each task in the chain. If I understand the rather vague documentation correctly I'd be able to synchronize using a chord containing all the chains but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the status of each chain.

I am at a loss here having no familiarity with celery design paradigms and the sparse documentation is of no help. what is the "right" (or least ugly) way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the result I want building lots of chains and then putting them all into a group and executing it. My code looks more or less like this:

```
res = []
for sequence in product(*input, *action):
    method = getattr(tasks, sequence[1]['method'])
    ch = chain(method.s(input_document, **(sequence[1])))
    for seq in sequence[2:]:
        method = getattr(tasks, seq['method'])
        ch |= method.s(**seq)
    res.append(ch)
r = group(res).apply_async()
r.save()
return r.id
```

So basically calculating the dot product of all input documents and actions (algorithmic setup), retrieve the corresponding method from the tasks module, chain them all together, put it all in a group, and execute it.

Additionally, accessing the chain results from the GroupResult seems to work if you don't forget to save/restore the GroupResult.